# Close pop up Window Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to access a 'download csv' button on this website using Selenium. https://fplreview.com/team-planner/#forecast_table. When I first click on the site I need to enter a 'Team ID' and click submit which is fine but then a popup ad appears and I cannot close it. I've tried a few approaches mainly using XPATH but it says the button is not there eventhough I add a sleep timer to wait for page to load etc. My end goal is to do this using requests but I'm trying to get it working using Selenium first. Thanks. Below is my code

```
`
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://fplreview.com/team-planner/#forecast_table')
    
    team_id = driver.find_element_by_name('TeamID')
    team_id.send_keys(123)
    team_id.submit()
    
    # click close button on ad.
    ad_path = '//*[@id="butt"]/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/article/div[2]/div/div[18]/div/div/div[3]/button'
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(ad_path)
    button.click()
    
    # export csv
    export_button = driver.find_element_by_id('exportbutton')
    export_button.click()
    
    driver.quit()

`
```

The error this generates

`

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="butt"]/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/article/div[2]/div/div[18]/div/div/div[3]/button"}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several waits are needed to make it work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://fplreview.com/team-planner/#forecast_table')

team_id = driver.find_element_by_name('TeamID')
team_id.send_keys(123)
team_id.submit()

# wait for the ad to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'orderModal_popop')))

# hide the ad
driver.execute_script("jQuery('#orderModal_popop').modal('hide');")

# export csv
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/article/div[2]/div/button[6]')))
export_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/article/div[2]/div/button[6]')
export_button.click()

# wait for download
time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried myself and got the same error. It seems that the program doesnt wait long enough, for me it crashed before the button even got loaded, which probably caused the error. No matter where you set the `webdriver.implicitly_wait('time')`it crashes before the button loaded. Id suggest to use an explicit wait as shown here: [Here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). I sadly didnt come to use it myself, so i cant suggest how to do it exactly, but it seems like this is the proper use for this problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are finding the right close button. This finds all elements with the id "close" and clicks the second element. Attempting to close the first element will raise an "ElementNotInteractableException".

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='close']")
button[1].click()
```

### Using Explicit Wait & Path to Correct Button

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

path = "//div[@id='orderModal_popop']/div[@class='modal-dialog']/div[@id='teamcolours']/div[@class='modal-header']/button[@id='close']"

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, path)
    )
)
```

This waits 10 seconds for the correct close button to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so i tried fixing the ad issue using this

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='close']")
sleep(1)
button.click()
```